# Algorithms for the minimization of pseudoconvex functions

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to minimize a twice-continuously differentiable strictly pseudoconvex function (which is not convex) from $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ (strictly positive reals)

I know that I can use gradient descent and find the only global minimum when the gradient is zero.

Can I also use Newton's method to find this minimum? In other words, is Newton's method guaranteed to converge for pseudoconvex functions?

A related question: can I use Nesterov acceleration technique to get faster convergence of gradient descent for pseudoconvex functions?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "strongly pseudoconvex"?

Comment: This is certainly not true for pseudoconvex functions in general since you could have a singular Hessian at some point and not be able to apply Newton's method.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: I meant "strictly", not "strongly", sorry. Thank you for your following comment.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: If you turn your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to construct a function function $f:R \rightarrow R$ that is strictly pseudoconvex but which has points where $f''(x)=0$.  If you applied Newton's method to such a function starting at a point where $f''(x)=0$, it would fail.

Here's a specific example.  We'll construct the function by starting with a second derivative that is non-negative but has some roots.  Let

$g(x)=(x-1)^{2}(x+1)^{2}x^{2}$.

Then integrate $g(x)$ to get the first derivative,

$h(x)=x^{7}/7-2x^5/5+x^3/3$

We'll integrate this one more time to get $f(x)$

$f(x)=x^{8}/56-x^{6}/15+x^{4}/12$

If you start Newton's method at $x_{0}=1$, then it will fail immediately due to the fact that $f''(x_{0})=0.$  It's easy to check that this function is strictly pseudoconvex (In fact, it's strictly convex.)

There are of course many ways of making Newton's method more robust- you could for example simply take a gradient step whenever the Hessian matrix is nearly singular.  Almost any general purpose nonlinear optimization routine should practically be able to handle this problem, particularly if the dimension is small.